# Change "settings" to "Logout" in ms teams search based messaging extension

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using MS Teams Search based messaging extension to search for notes and docs for my org., after the user has signed in.

[image]

Here, instead of "settings" , i want to use "Log Out", is there any way to do this?

Comment: is this related to python?

Comment: I used python to create this messaging extension...

Comment: Then, if you created it, can't you just change it to logout...?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of messaging extension to show settings option, i don't know how to change that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. You can not change the text for Settings. However, you can add new action command for Sign Out.

[image]

Please take a look at [example manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config/TeamsAppManifest/manifest.json#L73) for Messaging Extension auth sample.